# is it necessary to type-cast malloc and calloc

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

I was googling to find out the reason for type-casting of **malloc** and **calloc**. But, i only found *type-casting of **malloc** is not necessary since it return void pointer* but, what about **calloc**. This is the same reason for **calloc** too ???

Now, if we move back to first point, about return value of **malloc** and **calloc**. Then, i found that, *both are returning the allocated spaces*. So, i'm little bit confused here. So, my questions are

> 1. What is the return value of **malloc** and **calloc**
> 2. Is it necessary to type-cast **malloc** and **calloc**. And why ?

Comment: @hmjd may be.. but here i'm asking for both `malloc` and `calloc` too.

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate, but compilers are getting more pissy about requiring you to cast the void pointer to any other type - which flies in the face of the original purpose of a void pointer, that is was a universal type that could be cast and assigned to anything. This is more C "progress".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What is the return value of malloc and calloc?

It is a pointer to `void` (`void*`).

> Is it necessary to type-cast malloc and calloc. And why ?

No, because the conversion from a pointer to `void` to a pointer to object is implicit.

> **C11 (n1570), § 6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>   A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type.

It is right for both `malloc` and `calloc`.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc()`or `calloc()` returns `void *` which can be assigned to any pointer type .In C it's not necessary to typecast the `void*` since it's implicitly done by compiler.But in c++ it will give you error if you won't typecast

Answer (score 1):

> What is the return value of malloc() and calloc()?

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
```

`void*` is returned by both the functions.

> Is it necessary to type-cast malloc and calloc. And why ?

No. It is not required to typecast.  The `malloc()` and `calloc()` functions return a pointer to  the  allocated memory  that  is  suitably aligned for any kind of variable. On error, these functions return `NULL`.  `NULL` may also be returned by a successful call  to  `malloc()` with a size of zero, or by a successful call to `calloc()` with `nmemb` or size equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `malloc` and `calloc` is a `void*`. The address of the heap memory space allocated by these functions.

Both functions allocate memory. The only difference between them is that

- malloc simply allocates memory.
- calloc allocates the memory and initializes it to 0.

In C its not recommended to cast the return value of these functions.

In C++ it is mandatory to cast.