# Passing 2 dimensional array into a function using pointer C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here is an example of my code (magic square):

```
    int magicsqr(int *magic,int size);
    int main()
    {
        int size,*ptr;
        char stop;
        repeat:
        printf("Please Enter an Odd number for the magic square(3 or greater):\n");
        scanf("%d",&size);
        fflush(stdin);
        ptr=(int*)calloc(size*size,sizeof(int));
        while((size%2==0)||(size<=1))
        {
            printf("U entered a wrong number.\n");
            repeat1:
            printf("Do you wish to continue?(Y or N)\n");
            scanf("%c",&stop);
            fflush(stdin);
            if(stop=='Y'||stop=='y')
                goto repeat;
            else if(stop=='N'||stop=='n')
                printf("Thanks for trying our beta program.\n");
            else
            {
                printf("U entered a wrong character.\n");
                goto repeat1;
            }
        }
        magicsqr(ptr,size);
        return 0;
    }
    int magicsqr(int *magic,int size)
    {
        int i,j,num;
        i=1;
        j=(size+1)/2;
        for(num=1;num<=size*size;num++)
        {
            *(magic+i*size+j)=num;
            if(num%size==0){
                i++;
                continue;
                }
            if(i==1)
               i=size;
            else
               i--;
            if(j==size)
               j=1;
            else
               j++;
        }
        for(i=1;i<=size;i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            for(j=1;j<=size;j++)
                printf("%d\t",*(magic+i*size+j));
        }
}
```

so i got few questions that confused me ..

1- As far as i know `Arr[i][j]==*(Arr[i]+j)`
so why only this works : `*(magic+i*size+j)`.

2- I read a lot in passing 2 dimensional array into a function using pointers but somehow i am still confused, how to represent a 2D array or more in this code.

3- I am still a beginner in programming, so i wish if you could explain a little.

- Thanks a lot guys, finally i got it worked using pointer to pointer and array of pointers.

Comment: 1. Remove I/O code from your code and leave only important part. 2. Clarify what you expect and what you get actually

Comment: My code works well and print the result right but i need some explanation in my code that i dont know why it worked like this

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code. And `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: [How can I flush pending input so that a user's typeahead isn't read at the next prompt? Will `fflush(stdin)` work?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html)

Comment: Yeah it works fine with me b/c my compiler doesn't accept 2 inputs

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Ass far as i know Arr[i][j]==*(Arr[i]+j) so why only this works :
>   (magic+isize+j).

[Don't cast result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287888/is-it-necessary-to-type-cast-malloc-and-calloc) of `calloc` when yo are doing

```
ptr = calloc(size*size,sizeof(int));
```

It's allocating 1D array (or `ptr` is 1D array pointer ) so `(magic+isize+j)` this is working. it's just conversion of 2D index to 1D to access array.

> 2- I read a lot in passing 2 dimensional array into a function using
>   pointers but somehow i am still confused, how to represent a 2D array
>   or more in this code.

For passing 2 dimensional array into a function have look on [correct way of passing 2D array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a 2D array at all, but a one dimensional array which is used to imitate a 2D array.

So, the memory allocation is

```
ptr=calloc(size*size,sizeof(int));
```

This is an allocation for a 1D array of `(size * size)` elements

Data is accessed for this array like this

```
*(magic+i*size+j)=num;
```

Each element position is calculated by from the base index by adding the `no of rows` * `i` + `j`.

These are called flat arrays.

Comment: Now i get it but what should i do if wish to change it to a 2D ?

Comment: There are a lot of things you need to change. The declaration of ptr, the memory allocation, the function call, the function declaration and the function body will have to be modified to accept a 2D array instead of a 1D array. After that, you need to recompile it and see if any other changes are required. If the code is working, i don't think it is worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and ye the code is working but i am just testing different methods for more understanding

Comment: Try rewriting the whole thing, with a double pointer. You will get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it, thanks for helping.

```
int main()
{
char stop;
int i,j,size,num;
repeat:
printf("Please Enter an Odd number for the magic square(3 or greater):\n");
scanf("%d",&size);
fflush(stdin);
int **magic=(int**)malloc(size*sizeof(int*));   //size = row
if((size%2==0)||(size<=1))
{
    printf("U entered a wrong number.\n");
    repeat1:
    printf("Do you wish to continue?(Y or N)\n");
    scanf("%c",&stop);
    fflush(stdin);
    if(stop=='Y'||stop=='y')
        goto repeat;
    else if(stop=='N'||stop=='n')
        printf("Thanks for trying our beta program.\n");
    else
    {
        printf("U entered a wrong character.\n");
        goto repeat1;
    }
}

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    magic[i]=(int*)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        printf("%d\t",*(magic[i]+j));
}
i=0;
j=(size)/2;;
for(num=1;num<=size*size;num++)
{
    magic[i][j]=num;
    if(num%size==0){
        i++;
        continue;
        }
    if(i==0)
       i=size-1;
    else
        i--;
    if(j==size-1)
        j=0;
    else
        j++;
}
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        printf("%d\t",*(magic[i]+j));
}
return 0;
}
```